# Facebook graph api reactions total_count mismatching data node count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve all reactions from a post on facebook graph api v2.7. 
I'm using the following url:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/YYY/reactions?summary=total_count&limit=10000000&access_token=XXX

And i got an answer like:

```
    {
        data: [
            {
                id: ...,
                name: ...,
                type: ...
            },
            ...
        ],
        "summary": {
            "total_count": 2533
        }
    }
```

The summary says there's 2533 reactions but data length is 2466.
It happens for all posts with a big count of reactions.

I tried using paging with no success.
The API Reference of reactions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/reactions) says nothing about.

And i'm using an page access_token from an administrator user.

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it´s because some users deactivated the App platform, so they don´t show up with their names. But they do add to the `total_count`. As long as the `total_count` is the bigger number, you should not worry. If it´s the other way around, then it may be a bug.